# Why is this not cls-compliant?

Tags: c#, cls-compliant

From what I've been reading online, if the field is `private` it can start with a leading `_`. However when I do the following it complains? Is it because I'm returning the private field? Doesn't make sense to me since anything consuming this has no idea about _myObject so why would it matter?

```
private MyBusinessObject _myObjectBO;

protected MyBusinessObject MyObjectBO
{
    get { return _myObjectBO ?? (_myObjectBO= new MyBusinessObject()); }
}
```

Comment: What does the error say? What's `MyObject`?

Comment: The warning says: "Type of `My.Namespace.MyService.MyObjectBO` is not CLS-complaint". I'm just using this in a WCF Service to call my BO which has the usual methods to get data etc.

Comment: So how does `MyBusinessObject` look like? That's where the issue is.

Comment: The warning is saying that `MyBusinessObject` (the type of the property) is not compliant.

Comment: Thanks @svick and @SLaks! I won't point fingers, but somebody didn't mark a certain class library as `cls-compliant` when they added it to the solution... Message seemed a bit misleading since it was anchored on the object, but I guess if I would of referenced the rest of the objects I maybe would of thought about the dll class library itself. Either way, if one of you write an answer I'll mark it as answered. Thanks again!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The message is stating that the property's *type* is not compliant.
Check the `MyBusinessObject` class; many developers forgot to add `[assembly: CLSCompliant(true)]` (unfortunately, it isn't part of the standard template)

Answer (score 1):

Nothing about this is inherently not CLS Compliant. What does MyObject look like? I tested with the following code, and got no CLS compliance warnings at compile time:

```
[CLSCompliant(true)]
public class Program
{
    private MyObject _myObject;

    [CLSCompliant(true)]
    public MyObject ComplaintTypeBO
    {
        get { return _myObject ?? (_myObject = new MyObject()); }
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
    }
}

[CLSCompliant(true)]
public class MyObject
{
}
```